# Eclipse My project no longer shows up under Package Explore

Tags: java, eclipse

I have a project called card server2.  It disappeared from my package Explore and I can no longer work on it.  The files are still there.  I try to use import to get it back.  But there was a message saying project already existed in workspace.

his happen after I imported a project called chat server, which is working fine.

I was thinking about creating a new workspace and importing the project into this, but then I would have one work space with all my projects and one for just that project.
any ideas would be great!

Comment: Delete the physical files(project) from workspace and import it.

Comment: Try the Navigator view, can you spot your project there?

Comment: You don't need to delete the physical files from the workspace, just reimport it directly from the workspace files. It  will do the right thing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can reimport your project after moving it to another location ;)

Comment: Hi,THANK YOU, I did not think it would be this simple!

Answer (score 0):

Cut and paste the project from your workspace to another location and import it back. It should work fine.

Comment: Hi,Thank you for taking your time to answer my question, so simple :)

Answer (score 0):

navigate to window-show view-others-java-project explorer. if it already open close it and re-open it and you will find it .Hope that help.